# Can you specify different fonts for different browsers with CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've tried using em as well as px, but I cannot get a certain line of text to display at the same size in every browser. I know I'm reaching for a lot but I'm tasked with achieving a pixel-perfect development based on a mock-up, and need a certain text to span the width of an area left-to-right so that it all flushes from side to side with an image.

My last option is to use an image, which I don't want to do. I know that you can specify certain CSS parameters that work on the different browsers such as -moz-SOMECSSPROPERTY:some value; but can you do this with the font size so that one browser has it at one size, and another as another. Oddly enough too though this is actually only happening in the browsers that are on different OS's, i.e. - on my Mac it's as intended, and on Windows (same browsers) different.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be enough to specify the font on a per-browser basis, because (as you noticed) you'll also run into inconsistencies across platforms and devices.

If you want the text to always fit the image flush, the text pretty much has to be an image, too.

Comment: yes I'm figuring that, but I know I'm going to hear it. Thought I'd ask the guru's that abound here on the Stack ;-)